# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'backpack' before initialization at script.js:24:13

Tags: javascript, html

I have used

```
type="module"
```

while declaring the script tag in HTML file. I have also used

```
export default 'object name'
```

in both files, but I am not getting the reason why this error has occurred. I just want to access the backpack object in script.js file and vice versa.

script.js File

```js
 /**
 * Create a Backpack object, populate some HTML to display its properties.
 */

import backpack from "./backpack.js";

const markup = (backpack) => {
  return `
  <div>
    <h3>${backpack.name}</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Volume: ${backpack.volume}</li>
      <li>Color: ${backpack.color}</li>
      <li>Number of pockets: ${backpack.pocketNum}</li>
      <li>Strap lengths: L: ${backpack.strapLength.left}, R: ${
    backpack.strapLength.right
  } </li>
      <li>Top lid: ${backpack.lidOpen ? "Open" : "Closed"}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
`;
};

console.log(backpack);

const main = document.createElement("main");
main.innerHTML = markup(backpack);
document.body.appendChild(main);

export default markup;
```

backpack.js File

```js
import markup from "./script.js";

const backpack = {
  name: "Everyday Backpack",
  volume: 30,
  color: "grey",
  pocketNum: 15,
  strapLength: {
    left: 26,
    right: 26,
  },
  lidOpen: false,
  toggleLid: function (lidStatus) {
    this.lidOpen = lidStatus;
    updateBackpack(`Lid status changed.`);
  },
  newStrapLength: function (lengthLeft, lengthRight) {
    this.strapLength.left = lengthLeft;
    this.strapLength.right = lengthRight;
    updateBackpack(`Strap lengths updated.`);
  },
};

const updateBackpack = (update) => {
  let main = document.querySelector("main");
  main.innerHTML = markup(backpack);
  console.info(update);
};

export default backpack;
```

Comment: "The "Cannot access before initialization" error occurs when a variable declared using let or const is accessed before it was initialized in the scope. To solve the error, make sure to initialize the variable before accessing it." - what is at script.js:24:13" ?

Comment: This codesandbox shows the backpage OK: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-lehmann-k4wyhl?file=/src/backpack.js